# Derivative of a multiple of Heaviside step function

Tags: derivatives, dirac-delta, step-function

First of all, thanks for your time, I have a question. Let's assume that we have:
`f(x)=(Heaviside's step function)*e^(3x)`
Now let's assume to calculate the derivate of this function, why we have this:
[image]

The derivative of this function must be: `dirac*e^(3x)+ 3*e^(3x)`, but my book and Wolfram Alpha says that this is incorrect. Why have weonly `dirac+3*e^(3x)`?

Comment: Because $e^{3\times 0}=1$ so the two are the same

Comment: If you multiply a function by a Dirac delta function $\delta(x)$, the only thing that matters is the value of the function at $x=0$, since the delta function is zero elsewhere.

Comment: And the second term has a step function as a factor: it is not just the exponential. You just apply the product rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\delta(x) = \delta(x) e^{3x}$ for all $x$.

This is because $e^{3x}$ evaluated at $x=0$ is $1$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).